# Gray scaled image from 1 channel to 3 channels, with the 2 extra channels made only by zeros

Tags: python-3.x, image

Is it possible to make images with 1 channel to images with 3 channels by adding 2 channels that only contains zeros?

This is the file with images that I want to convert to 3 channels images by adding 2 extra channels made only by zeros

```py
images.shape
(100, 120, 120, 1)
```

This is the code that I am using now to import images in 1 channel

```py
def loadImages():

    dirname = '/c/disk/img_t1/'
    x_orig = np.zeros((100, 120, 120), dtype=np.float32) 

    for f in range(x_orig.shape[0]):
        img    = Image.open(dirname + 'img_t1_%05d.tiff' % (f))  
        img    = np.array(img)
        x_orig[f] = img

    
    path = '/c/labels.csv'    
    labels = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=["proportional", "category"],
                       sep=";" )
    y_orig = np.array(labels['category'])

    return x_orig, y_orig


x, y = loadImages()
plt.imshow(x[3])
```

And this is how the image looks like

[image]

And if from the same code I just add .convert('RGB) from the package PIL to add the other 2 channels

```py
def loadImages():

    dirname = '/c/disk/img_t1/'
    x_orig = np.zeros((100, 120, 120,3), dtype=np.float32) 

    for f in range(x_orig.shape[0]):
        img    = Image.open(dirname + 'img_t1_%05d.tiff' % (f)).convert('RGB')  
        img    = np.array(img)
        x_orig[f] = img

    
    path = '/c/labels.csv'    
    labels = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=["proportional", "category"],
                       sep=";" )
    y_orig = np.array(labels['category'])

    return x_orig, y_orig


x, y = loadImages()
plt.imshow(x[3])
```

The image looks like this

[image]

So I would like something like this

```py
images.shape
(100, 120, 120, 3)
```

Comment: If you have a greyscale (single channel) image and you add two extra channels of zeroes, the original data will be interpreted as red, and your image will no longer appear grey but red because the red channel has data and no shades of green or blue are present. Is that what you want? Normally, if you want to make a single channel into a 3-channel image and it still to look grey, you would replicate the single channel 3 times to make Red=Green=Blue which means grey.

Comment: I tried to replicate in the beginning but instead of turning grey it turns only with parts that are completely black or completely white

Comment: How about we start with you showing one image, and your code for loading it and your attempt to convert it into 3-channel? Then we can progress from there.

Comment: Until you show some code and images, we have no idea what type of images you are using (JPEG/PNG/GIF/TIFF), whether they are integers/floats,  with or without alpha/transparency, which library you are using (OpenCV, PIL/Pillow, Wand) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to do some training for machine learning or somesuch.

I think your file is maybe a single channel, 32-bit floating point TIFF - although you have actually shared a PNG file.

I think the issue is that PIL/Pillow doesn't support RGB (3-channel) float - see [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

I don't know what you plan to do next with your data, so I don't know what image processing functionality you need. But I suspect you may need to move to a different library - OpenCV, or Wand, or pyvips or ...